# SFTP File to Server Without Local User Access

Tags: certificate-authority, sftp

Need to allow outside OpenSSH client to SFTP file to Reflection Secure IT Server without the need for local user's PKI.
In the past, I had a server with a local user account.
The client gave me his public key and I authorized it, but this requires a local user account on the server.

I am trying to find a method to allow the same without the need for a local user account.
I assume public/private keys only work when there is a local user account to connect as.
Is there a way to use a CA Trusted Certificate for this?

Comment: Even if this was possible, I'm not sure how it would work.  Without the user's public key associated with a user account on the server, how would the server know what privileges the user has when the user authenticates with this public key?

Comment: Unless you want to enable anonymous access (not recommended), wouldn't each user *have* to have a local (or possibly ldap) account to authenticate to? That will require a username and password, or username and public key.

Comment: There is nothing inherent in the SSH/SFTP protocol itself which requires a local user for key based authentication. You are asking if a specific proprietary SFTP server product implements the feature you need. Please check the documentation of the product or ask the vendor for this.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use SFTP on a system without having a local user account on that system.  For example, ProFTPd supports SFTP with virtual accounts, such that multiple users can have individually scoped access to various files and folders without needing individual system accounts.  In addition, it's possible to use a library like libssh to emulate a real file system without needing any local accounts at all.

However, not all SSH implementations support this.  OpenSSH, for example, usually requires a local user account.  Whether your implementation supports this is probably best found in the documentation for your implementation.